# TrainDeepLearningModel tool not responding in arcgis pro

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, arcgis

Platform: Precision 5820, 32G, rtx4000; Win 10 Pro, Arcgis Pro 2.6 concurrent license;

Issue:
I installed the deep learning tools following the guidelines provided here:
[deeplearninginstallation](https://github.com/Esri/deep-learning-frameworks/blob/master/README.md?rmedium=links_esri_com_b_d&rsource=https%3A%2F%2Flinks.esri.com%2Fdeep-learning-framework-install)
tersorflow was not found after installation so I manually installed the 2.1.0 version. I now have arcgis 1.8.2, pro 2.6, fastai 1.0.60, python 3.6.12, pytorch 1.4.0, tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0; environment check in arcgis pro python seemed fine.

[image: checking env in arcgis pro]

However, after I select toolbox-image analyst-deeplearning-traindeeplearningmodel, the program seems to go into a hang, with most buttons disabled/unresponsive, this would continue until I force terminate the program. I also ran into "tool not licensed" twice, which was gone after I restarted the program; and a "name 'CallBackHandler' is not defined" once, which was also gone after I restarted.

I tried runing the command from the arcgis pro python prompt:

```
TrainDeepLearningModel(r"**", r"**", 40, "RETINANET", 16, "# #", None, "RESNET50", None, 10, "STOP_TRAINING", "FREEZE_MODEL")
```

executing the command would also send the program into a hang similar to the previous one. Monitor shows that ram and GPU usage haven't changed much, so I left the program running for an hour before forcibly terminating it.

I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone can tell me what the issues are here. I'll post any other env parameters if anyone requires. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I got the tool up and running now by running `conda install -c pytorch -c fastai fastai=1.0.54 pytorch=1.1.0 torchvision scikit-image` and removing all the conflicting specifications in the cloned arcgispro-py3 env that I had. Now I still don't understand what went wrong. Presumably one or more packages in the env was conflicting. But seeing as I'm not a python expert, I couldn't identify the exact issue.

Before this I tried the versions stated here [deeplearning install guide](https://pro.arcgis.com/zh-cn/pro-app/tool-reference/image-analyst/pdf/deep_learning_install.pdf), but wasn't able to get pass tensorflow-gpu because python kept checking conflications. Now I actually don't have tensorflow-gpu in the env. I have tensorflow 2.1.0, keras-applications 1.0.8/base 2.3.1/preprocesing 1.1.0 (no keras-gpu), scikit-image 0.17.2, pillow 6.2.1, fastai 1.0.54, pytorch 1.1.0, libtiff 4.0.10. Some are different from what the guideline provided.

Thing is when I ran the process, CPU usage was up and GPU wasn't despite the fact that I specified GPU as the processing core. But I have much more pressing things to do right now like getting the analysis finished. So I'll probably tweek the env around a little after I'm done with this bit and see what happens. Meanwhile, anyone's input is still welcome.